# Preventing other signed-in users from accessing 'edit' page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a small web app that allows users to list their goals. I want the users to only be able to edit their own content. I've already got an authenticate function as a before_filter which checks to make sure someone is signed in, but it doesn't check if the user is the creator of the content. I tried creating a second before_filter called correct_user that has the code as follows:

```
def correct_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to(user_path(current_user)) unless current_user?(@user)
end
```

In addition here is the server output from running a get request to edit my own content

```
Started GET "/goals/31/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-18 15:22:38 -0400
  Processing by GoalsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"31"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 101) LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 31) LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/101 Completed 302 Found in 49ms
Completed 302 Found in 49ms
```

For clarity, the user_id I'm using is 101, and the goal_id I'm trying to edit is 31. Could someone explain exactly what is going on?

Also, I'm aware you can navigate this problem by using a gem called CanCan (as a similar question was answered about this), but is there a way to do it without using a gem? It seems like my simple little function should work, but could someone explain why it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` is the hash of all parameters being sent (via url or form fields, etc) to your action.  The name of the parameter, if present in the URL, is defined in your routes file.  For your goals controller routes, you probably (presumably) have:

```
goals_path: /goals/
goal_path: /goals/:id
edit_goal_path: /goals/:id/edit
```

Because you are getting `/goals/31/edit`, `params[:id]` is 31, the id of the goal you are editing.  The first line in `correct_user` is finding the User whose id matches the id in the params hash (goal_id).  So really, you should be doing something like this:

```
def correct_user
  user = Goal.find(params[:id]).user if params[:id]
  redirect_to user_path(current_user) unless current_user?(user)
end
```

This says, find the goal that somebody wants to edit (from params[:id]), and give me the user associated with it ( you didn't post your goal model, I am assuming Goal belongs_to :user but you may have named it "creator" or "owner" instead).  Redirect if the user is not the same as the current user logged in.  Your previous code was attempting to find a User with the same id as the goal being edited.

Comment: That clears things up a lot, thank you! But why do you have "if params[:id]" appended to the end of the first line? What are the consequences of leaving it off?

Comment: Depends on how you define your before_filter.  If the before filter runs on every action, it will throw a RecordNotFound exception on collection actions (index, new).  If your before filter only runs before edit, update, destroy, create, then there is probably no need. Basically that makes the first line not execute if it can't find an id in the params hash, instead of executing and throwing an exception.

Comment: Yes, I only have it running on certain actions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Given the following assumptions:

1. User model: `has_many :goals`
2. Goal model: `belongs_to :user`
3. Route to edit goal: `/goals/:id/edit`
4. Goals controller, edit action is authenticated (so you will definitely have a `current_user`)

You should be able to access the goal like this:

```
def edit
  @goal = current_user.goals.find(params[:id]) rescue redirect_to(user_path current_user)
end
```

This will scope the find to goals belonging to the `current_user`, so `@goal` will always belong to the correct user.

Answer (score 1):

the parameter id in the params hash refers to the goal id, not the user id. Hence why you're seeing a problem.

Likely what you want to do is something like

```
def correct_user
   @goal = Goal.find(params[:id])
   redirect_to(user_path(current_user)) unless current_user?(@goal.user)
end
```

Comment: `@goal = User.find` ?  Might have a typo there! :)

Answer (score 0):

Others answered your main problem but I want to say this: I would strongly recommend using CanCan, even for a very small project. It's very easy to use, and it will help you alot, and you'll have awesome clean code

for example, in your situation you could put this line in `ability.rb` to manage updating a user's goals

`can :update, Goal, :user_id => user.id`

and in your controller just do a `load_and_authorize_resource` at the top. No manually before_filters, no checking for any conditions or anything like that.

and wherever you will need to put something about editing a goal, like say in an index view, when listing the links you'll just put something like `link_to_if(can?(:update, goal) , "edit goal", goal_path(goal) ){}`