# Validation to add only one biography for single person

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two model user and biography, both has one-to-one association and i want to user to add only one biography..here is the model:-

```
 class Biography < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :biography, :date, :title, :individual_id  
  belongs_to :user
 end

 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :biography
 end
```

How can i validate user so that he can add only one biography.
please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have check out this [link. (source)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

> A belongs_to association sets up a one-to-one connection with another
>   model, such that each instance of the declaring model “belongs to” one
>   instance of the other model.
>
> A has_one association also sets up a one-to-one connection with
>   another model, but with somewhat different semantics (and
>   consequences). This association indicates that each instance of a
>   model contains or possesses one instance of another model.

But if you wanted you could add a :before_save method that will check user.biography does not return something unexpected, but I don't think this is neccessary.

EDIT AFTER COMMENTS:

Try something like a before_filter...

```
before_filter :check_user, :only => [:new]
```

This will call the method before the controller action is called. Then you can create the method that will check the current_user has a biography and direct them to it. This is a starting point..

```
def check_user
 current_user.nil? ? redirect_to(new_biography_path) : redirect_to(edit_biography_path) 
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks CIH for quick responce.you are right but my problem is that when i go to '/biography/new', it agian create new biography but at that time i want to redirect user back to its previous biography and no more than one biography is added..

Comment: Ah I see, well you have a few options. You could check if the current_user has a biography already and if they do direct them to it or alternatively hide the link to new biography in the view, maybe show the edit link if they have one?

Comment: I already have hide new link but any one can go in new page by typing '/biography/new' in url.. Is there any method or validation so that if user use '/biography/new' in url though they redirct back to previous biography..

Comment: Sure you can, try something like this... `code` before_filter :check_user!, :only => [:new]

Comment: before_filter :check_user!, :only => [:new] and                  def check_user!
    if @biography.biography.present?
      redirect_to user_path
    end  end                                                                  its gives error ' undefined method `biography' for  nil:NilClass'

Comment: you have not declared @biography it sounds like look at the example above, are you using authentication? can you access current_user

Comment: i use this in method:- current_user.nil? ? redirect_to(new_biography_path) : redirect_to(edit_biography_path(@biography))   but it give error 'No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"biographies", :locale=>:en, :id=>nil}'

Comment: OK well you have a few probs there. Your not passing through the biography id correctly, @biography.id will work assuming you have set the biography instance variable in the controller. But you also dont have a route set up for the edit biographies path, can you show me what is in your routes.rb file I can take a look.

Comment: resources :biographies and   resources :users are in routes.rb

Comment: OK I think it is to do with the object your passing to the path, first try an id of a biography you know exists, then you will need to do some debugging in the controller, check how you can access the id of the biography, maybe params[:id] then set @biography = Biography.find(params[:id]) something like that I guess. Please accept my answer if this has been helpful, I think I have answered your original question (and a few more :-)

Comment: Thanks cih for yours use-full help.I got solution.               
  def check_user! 
   @biography = Biography.find_by_user_id(current_user)
   if @biography.present?
      redirect_to(edit_biography_path(@biography))
   end
   return true
  end

Comment: hey cih,there is a one another problem. i want to allow user to edit only there own biography but from url one user can edit other's biography EX."http://0.0.0.0:3000/biographies/8/edit"..here user can easily change id..how can i stop that..i need your kind help.thanks i advance

Comment: The answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050670/preventing-other-signed-in-users-from-accessing-edit-page